# Example image that is degraded by shot noise and easily misinterpreted?

Tags: image-processing

For illustrating the effects of shot noise (more precisely, emitter failure in fluorescence imaging) I am looking for a good example image. The image should ideally be easily misinterpreted, especially by non-aided human analysts, when a fair amount of shot noise is applied to it.

Does anyone know of such an image?

Comment: Image of what?  After all, you can readily produce shot noise with any digital camera merely by taking a grossly underexposed snapshot.

Comment: @whuber: Of what is exactly my question. I can add shot noise to pretty much any image, but it's often not very easy to see how the image might become ambiguous and easy to misinterpret when shot noise is applied. I'm looking for an image where this is easy to see.

Comment: This question isn't really on-topic here.  The DSP and photo mods don't think it's on-topic on their sites, either, because it is asking about *human interpretation.*  Thus it fits neither under stats, image processing, nor photography.  A DSP mod pointed out that Wikipedia appears to have a nice set of images at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3APhoton-noise.jpg.  **Update** The DSP site is willing to take a look--they might have someone expert in this issue.  (Thanks.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like Figure 4 in this paper by Dumitriu, Rodriguez, and Morrison (2011) work? They imaged the spines on a neuron using six different gain settings, which produce different amounts of shot noise. One can see how the putative shape of the spine changes based on the amount of noise present. This example might be a little esoteric for a general audience, but it does sound like you're doing some kind of microscopy, so perhaps it's a good fit.

Dumitriu, D, Rodriguez A, and Morrison JH. High-throughput, detailed, cell-specific neuroanatomy of dendritic spines using microinjection and confocal microscopy. Nat Protoc. 2011 Aug 25;6(9):1391-411. doi: 10.1038/nprot.2011.389.
[Article at Nature Protocols](http://www.nature.com/nprot/journal/v6/n9/full/nprot.2011.389.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can expect small-size type printed in color with low intensity contrast (say, orange letters on blue background of similar brightness) to become illegible with a lot of shot noise. Something like http://img.ctrlv.in/4f5641aede8eb.jpg but with much more noise.

Answer (score 1):

Many [captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)s,
especially those mixing text and lines,
are difficult to read and would become worse
with added noise.